# Using Google Fonts with SVG <object>

Tags: html, css, svg, fonts

I'm embedding SVGs in my page with the `<object>` tag, and they're supposed to utilize Google Fonts (e.g. [Roboto](https://www.google.com/fonts#UsePlace:use/Collection:Roboto)). However, the SVGs aren't picking these fonts up and instead default to system fonts.

What am I doing wrong? Does every SVG require that the font itself be embedded in `<style>`?

**Example code:**

```
<head>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,100,100italic,300,300italic,400italic,500,500italic,700,700italic,900,900italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>

<body>
    <object width="250" height="200" type="image/svg+xml" data="img/popup_image.svg"></object>
</body>
```

**SVG snippet:**

```
<text font-size="14" fill="#333" font-family="Roboto">Words go here</text>
```

Comment: How does your code look like?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. As I said, it's using the object tag to show an SVG, and that SVG is referencing Google Fonts for its <text> attributes. I'll update my question above in case I'm not being clear.

Comment: No this won't work....it's like trying to change the font in an **image** with CSS...not going to happen. If the SVG was *inline* it probably would though.

Comment: You need to put the link element in the same file as the svg i.e in popup_image.svg

Comment: @RobertLongson Can you provide a link or example of this working?

Comment: What's confusing you about putting the `<link>` element in the SVG file.

Comment: @RobertLongson I guess where and how exactly. In a `<defs></defs>`? Inside a `<style>`? Just looking for an example of the proper syntax, because it's throwing errors doing both of those things.

Comment: You can put it anywhere you like.

Comment: @RobertLongson That is simply false.

Comment: Really!?: [Try reading this w3c discussion then](https://www.w3.org/2015/02/11-svg-minutes.html#item09)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The browser treats SVG text as regular HTML text.  In other words, any text elements in your SVG must be styled like normal HTML elements (like a `<span>`, for example).  You need to embed your font in your SVG in the form of a CSS `@import`.  Look through the XML of your SVG for the `<defs>` section.  Then, add this code to it:

```
<defs>
  <style type="text/css">
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,100,100italic,300,300italic,400italic,500,500italic,700,700italic,900,900italic');
 </style>
</defs>
```

Next, update your `<text>` element to be like this:

```
<text font-size="14" fill="#333" style="font-family: 'Roboto';">
   Words go here
</text>
```

If you want more information about this, you might try this website: http://nimbupani.com/about-fonts-in-svg.html.  It has some pretty good information on fonts in embedded SVGs.  A working example of this can be found here:  https://github.com/marians/test-webfonts-in-svg.

Comment: Appreciate the effort, but unfortunately this did not work as I'd hoped.

Comment: Looks like you were close! Doing `@import url:()` seems to be working... still testing though.

Comment: If you get it working, let me know so I can edit my answer so it can be useful to others  :-)

Comment: No `CDATA` required. Just use: `@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Sonsie+One');`. A working example comparison can be found here: https://github.com/marians/test-webfonts-in-svg

Comment: Doesn't seem to work anymore, checked your example on github.

Comment: This is good solutions and its working, but font is not working when i take svg file in html. have you any solution ?

Comment: Google Fonts appends a '&display=swap' to the suggested css import statement. Firefox complains about this and refuses to render. It suffices to simply remove this suffix to make it work/render again.

Comment: @Ideogram apparently some modern browser complain about the suffix `display:swap`, so removing it successful rendered the font. However, does anyone know what this suffix does specifically?

Answer (score 18):

Some suggestions if you want to make your logo portable and available offline you should *consume* and *embed* the smallest version of your font possible.

First, **optimize the font size**, by only pulling in the stroke weights and characters you actually need.

So instead of this:

```
https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,100,100italic,300,300italic,400italic,500,500italic,700,700italic,900,900italic
```

Condense the options and also add the `?text=abc` param to only grab a subset of glyphs like this:

```
https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:700&text=Words%20go%20here
```

Inside your svg, you can include a [`@font-face`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face) declaration in a stylesheet in the `<defs>` tag like this:

```html
<defs>
  <style>
    @font-face {
      font-family: "Sample font";
      src: url("data:application/font-woff;charset=utf-8;base64,<b64>") format("woff2");
    }
  </style>
</defs>
```

Grab the file by navigating to the google fonts stylesheet and downloading the actual .woff2 file.  You can convert it to a b64 string using [base64-encoder](https://www.giftofspeed.com/base64-encoder/) or read more at [Converting and rendering web fonts to base64](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26867893/1366033).  Take that string and include it in your file.  Just for clarity, you could also specify the [unicode range](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face/unicode-range) on the font-face to make explicit that you're only pulling in some characters

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
     viewBox="0 0 280 140" width="300">

  <defs>

    <style>
      /* https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Patrick+Hand&text=KAM */
      @font-face {
        font-family: 'Patrick Hand';
        /* src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/l/font?kit=LDI1apSQOAYtSuYWp8ZhfYeMXNDN0vF8&skey=7fb0ea6515a61339&v=v11) format('woff2') */
        src: url(data:application/font-woff;charset=utf-8;base64,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) format('woff2');
        unicode-range: U+004B, U+0041, U+004D
      }
      text { 
        font-size: 140px;
        font-family: 'Patrick Hand', cursive;
        font-weight: 700; 
      }
    </style>
  </defs> 

    <text x="51"  y="132" rotate="-30">K</text>
    <text x="100" y="100" rotate="0">A</text>
    <text x="150" y="95"  rotate="30">M</text>

</svg>
```

**See Also**:

- [How do I embed Google Web Fonts into an SVG?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/5167/35880)

Comment: The font is still not displayed correctly in Ie or edge. It defaults a different font in those browsers. Is there a fix for that?

Comment: @theyuv, the above snippet only inlines the font file for *woff2*, which is not supported by IE11.  You could add fallback support for [other font formats](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40533065/1366033) for legacy compatibility

Comment: Google only seems to from the font in TTF does this method work with TTF? I tried but couldn't get it working.

Answer (score 2):

Kyle's answer is awesome, but didn't quite work for me, but it lead me to the right answer:

#### You can define the font as `local` if you already have it on the page

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Bitter';
  src: local('Bitter');
}
```

I'm making a website where I'm already using certain fonts and couldn't get them to load, but ideally I wouldn't even have to anyway since they're already loaded. This solution worked perfectly for me.