# How to get a Google Font working inside an inline SVG?

Tags: css, svg, google-fonts

Here is a very simplified version of my HTML document.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
 <div style=" width:256px; height:256px; margin:20px auto; ">

  <svg id="artwork" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 256 256">
   <style type="text/css"> /*internal CSS of the inline SVG*/
    /* <![CDATA[ */
    @font-face {
     font-family: "M PLUS 1p";
     src: url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=M+PLUS+1p');
    }
    /* ]]> */
   </style>

   <a xlink:href="#">
    <circle cx="57" cy="57" r="54.5" fill="#767dcc"/>
    <text transform="translate(33.916 87)" font-size="90" font-family="M PLUS 1p">1</text>
   </a>
  </svg>

 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Specifically I am concerned with this part:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "M PLUS 1p";
  src: url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=M+PLUS+1p');
}
```

...and this part:

```
font-family="M PLUS 1p"
```

It renders the "1" with the browser's default font, and looks like this:

[image]

<sup>Above screenshot is from Firefox</sup>

What the "1" glyph of the font *Mplus 1p* actually looks like is this:

[image]

<sup>Above screenshot is from TextEdit</sup>

I have been looking at [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36253961/), which has two answers. When I use the method recommended in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36254302/2454914) it works if I use the font recommended in that answer, but not with the font I'm trying to use.

`@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=M PLUS 1p');`

^ This didn't work.

[The other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53674218/2454914) seems like a more reasonable approach because `font-family` can be defined and reused easily.

I am using the link provided by Google, but it's not working:

`https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=M+PLUS+1p`

Seeing that Google's URL substitutes space characters for `+` I thought the following might work:

`@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=M+PLUS+1p');`

But this also has not worked. Here's my most up-to-date effort:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
 <div style=" width:256px; height:256px; margin:20px auto; ">

  <svg id="artwork" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 256 256">
   <defs>
    <style type="text/css"> /*internal CSS of the inline SVG*/
       /* <![CDATA[ */
       @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=M+PLUS+1p:400');
       /* ]]> */
    </style>
   </defs>

   <a xlink:href="#">
    <circle cx="57" cy="57" r="54.5" fill="#767dcc"/>
    <text transform="translate(33.916 87)" font-size="90" font-family="M PLUS 1p">1</text>
   </a>
  </svg>

 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

It's probably a matter of one syntax problem throwing the whole thing off, but I haven't been able to pin it down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right way is using `@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=M PLUS 1p');` and set your `font-family` in css too

```
text {
   font-family: 'M PLUS 1p';
}
```

Inline `font-family` just not works. I'm not sure it is a valid property or not

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
  <div style=" width:256px; height:256px; margin:20px auto; ">

    <svg id="artwork" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 256 256">
   <style type="text/css"> 
        @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=M+PLUS+1p');
        text {
          font-family: 'M PLUS 1p';
        }
   </style>

   <a xlink:href="#">
    <circle cx="57" cy="57" r="54.5" fill="#767dcc"/>
    <text transform="translate(33.916 87)" font-size="90" font-family="M PLUS 1p">1</text>
   </a>
  </svg>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! It's unexpected that even with spaces in the URL (`M PLUS 1p`) it still works! But I will go with the example syntax from your snippet (`M+PLUS+1p`) just to be certain.