# Directly embedding the woff font into blogger

Tags: html, css, blogger, woff

I am absolutely a novice in the field of html / css programming. I have a font file with extension .woff etc. I know, I may upload it on a server and later on use it with the help of css files generated from tools like fontsquirrel. However, I want to explore the option of getting the font into simple html or css codes so that I may use it on forums like blogger without having to host the font file elsewhere. Is it technically possible? Thank you.

Comment: this may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26867893