# How can I embed a variable font as base64?

Tags: css, variables, base64, embed, woff2

I’m trying to keep HTTP requests at a minimum in the website I’m developing. [FontSquirrel](https://fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator) and [Transfonter](https://transfonter.org) have been plenty useful to encode WOFF2 into base64, but I’ve had no luck with variable fonts and keeping all their features/axis (they result in static fonts).

Is there a way I can encode WOFF2 variable fonts into base64 and keep all their customizable goodness?

Comment: Does the conversion method given by @ilyich in 2019 at [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26867893/converting-and-rendering-web-fonts-to-base64-keep-original-look help?

Comment: Yes! Actually it worked seamlessly.