# Server fonts not working in internet explorer 11

Tags: internet-explorer, font-face

I use @font-face on my web page for change font. If i use local files with fonts([route for font from my pc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56rJH.png)), all work fine font look like this: [needed font](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUY87.png) . But if I try to use server file from same directory([server font file route](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1ve6.png)) IE received this font I see it in [dev tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LjVFx.png) but font not working and looks like [standart font](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rnKky.png)

Answer (score 0):

I not found good solution, but I fixed it used base64 converter from this answer: [Converting and rendering web fonts to base64 - keep original look](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26867893/converting-and-rendering-web-fonts-to-base64-keep-original-look)

Converter:

```js
function base64convert (files) {
  console.clear()
  const reader = new FileReader()
  reader.onload = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.result)
  }
  reader.readAsDataURL(files[0])
}
```

```html
<input type="file" onchange="base64convert(this.files)">
```

And included my ttf font file as base64 string.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'myfont';
    src: url("<<copied base64 string>>");
}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.