# How to use woff file for font in Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, add-on, google-apps-marketplace, woff

I want to use the **woff** file in my Google **App Script** project. I'm not getting how to **upload a woff** file in the Google App script. because there are only two file options: one is **HTML** and the second is **script**. I want to use the **woff** file in my project with **font face CSS**.

Can anyone guide me on this?

Comment: Have you checked the method by converting your `woff` file into **base64** & then add it as a CSS `@font-face` declaration in your `HTML` file's CSS style? For more details you can check [this existing stackoverflow post.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26867893)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I had used the woff file and in that answer, they had used ttf file. So is that solution work for the woff file also?

Answer (score 0):

## SUGGESTION

> ***NOTE**: This sample is intended to serve as a starting point or reference for your project. It's important to note that the community members do not provide coding services.*

[As per the existing post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26867893/converting-and-rendering-web-fonts-to-base64-keep-original-look), a ***woof*** file can also be used in the same method. I conducted a quick test for your reference, as shown below.

Essentially, all you need to do is convert your woof file into the ***base64*** format. You can do a Google search on several online tools for this, such as [this sample resource](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4B4E.png) or [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lRrH3.png).

## Demo

1. Say I want to use this woof file:

[image]

2. On my Google Apps Script html (`Index.html`) file's style tag, I have pasted the converted ***woof*** file to ***base64*** `@font-face` declaration as seen below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <base target="_top">
  <style>
    @font-face {
      font-family: "BigParty4Blue";
      /* Add other properties here, as needed. For example: */
      /*
      font-weight: 100 900;
      font-style: normal italic;
      */
      src: url(data:font/woff;base64,<THE_CONVERTED_BASE64_DATA>);
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <h1 style="font-family: 'BigParty4Blue', normal italic;  font-size: 67px;">Hello, woff test</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

3. Deployed & tested the `html` as a web app. You may also review the actual test [here](https://jsfiddle.net/7543mbzd/).

[image]

## Reference

- [CSS @font-face Rule](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_font-face_rule.php)