# Trouble Rendering Custom WOFF Font in Web Application

Tags: html, css, fonts

I'm currently working on a web application and trying to implement a custom font for certain elements using the @font-face rule in CSS. I've followed the standard procedure to define the font and applied it to specific elements, but I'm facing issues with rendering the font properly.

Here's the relevant code I'm using:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: swiper-icons;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: url('data:application/font-woff;charset=utf-8;base64,d09GRgABAAAAAAZgABAAAAAAD...'); /* Rest of the base64-encoded font data */
}

.my-custom-font {
    font-family: "swiper-icons", sans-serif;
}
```

I've decoded the base64 string and saved the font file with a .woff extension. However, when I apply the my-custom-font class to elements, the font doesn't seem to render as expected. I've tried using an online font rendering tool (https://fontdrop.info) to preview the font, but it's not working there either.

Things I've checked and tried:

- I made sure that I decoded the entire base64 string correctly.
- I've verified that the font file is saved in a valid format.
- I've used the correct font-family name ("swiper-icons") in my CSS.
- I've inspected the browser's console, but there are no error messages related to font loading or rendering.
  Is there something I might be missing or doing incorrectly? Are there any additional steps I need to take to ensure the font renders correctly? Could there be compatibility issues with certain font formats or online rendering tools? Any guidance on how to troubleshoot and resolve this font rendering issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The fact you can't inspect the font in fontdrop indicates you might have accidentally switched file types: so the original - I guess an icon font - might actually be a woff2 (currently not supported by fontdrop) but saved as a woff. This post might also be helpful ["Converting and rendering web fonts to base64 - keep original look"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26867893/converting-and-rendering-web-fonts-to-base64-keep-original-look). Please elaborate, how you're applying this font - quite likely you'll have rather cryptic PUA unicode points to display certain icons.